# Internal Server Error (500) when calling WCF service that should send email

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF Service that is designed to send an email using my company's email server (hiding the server name for security reasons, but that's not the problem, trust me):

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Public Sub SendCarrierEmail(email As String, from As String, cc As String, subject As String, personalMessage As String, laneInfo As String(), comments As String, signature As String)mail.To.Add(email)
    mail.CC.Add(cc)
    mail.Bcc.Add(email)
    mail.From = New MailAddress(from)
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.Body += personalMessage
    For i As Integer = 0 To laneInfo.Length
        mail.Body += laneInfo(i)
    Next
    mail.Body += comments & Environment.NewLine & signature
    Try
        client.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

The service is called from javascript like so:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    sendEmail();
});
function sendEmail() {
var service = new //(namespace for my javascript proxy);

var email = "test@test.com"
var from = "test@test.com"
var cc = "test@test.com"
var subject = "Test"
var personalMessage = "This is a test"
var laneInfo = ["test","20","test","test","test","test"]
var comments = "also test"
var signature = "Test";

service.SendCarrierEmail(email, from, cc, subject, personalMessage, laneInfo, comments, signature)
}
```

I know that the proxy is being called because I can make direct calls to other functions with the same syntax, but for some reason as soon as I try to pass it parameters I get an internal server error. I've also tried to do the same call by making an $.ajax({}) call but get the same result. When debugging with the developer tools in the browser I can tell that the request is being made with a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"email":"test@test.com","from":"test@test.com","cc":"test@test.com","subject":"Test","personalMessage":"This is a test","laneInfo":["test","20","test","test","test","test"],"comments":"also test","signature":"Test"}
```

So it looks like everything should work to me, but I assume that I have a formatting error somewhere along the line and would appreciate any direction.

Comment: How are you hosting the WCF Service?

Comment: I'm self-hosting the service currently, it's within the same project that I'm trying to use it in.